# How to add these PDF documents to a SQL Server database through Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new web developer and my company uses the following procedure in hosting the web based applications in its servers: the application should be in a server and the database in another different server. Now, in one of the developed system that has no administration part, they want me to add two PDF documents in its database.

I went to the database and found the table that is responsible about this issue. The design of table is as following:

**Reports** Table

```
ID, Category, Title, URL, Date, Hits
```

In the `URL` column, the developer of that system inserted data like this (`example.pdf`). I went through the source code of the system to see if these documents are uploaded to the `Application` folder in the applications server, but I could not be able to see anything.

So how can I upload these two files? And where will they be stored?